# How to refer to all extended types in xml schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

In my XML schema file I have the following base type which has some attributes:

```
<xs:complexType name="block">
    <xs:attribute name="blockid" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

and several other types obtained by extending it, to allow additional attributes or subelements:

```
<xs:complexType name="wall">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="block">
            <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="height" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="key">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="block">
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="keyid" type="xs:integer"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

and others.

Now I want to define an element which can have as subelements any of these extended types, but not the base type.
I now I can do the following:

```
<xs:complexType name="room">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="wall" type="wall"/>
        <xs:element name="key" type="key"/>
        <xs:element .../>
        and so on for each extended type
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

However, since in the future I may add other extended types, and all of them can be types of subelements of a room element, is there a way to tell that any type extended from block is allowed instead of mentioning the extended types one by one?
Instead of referencing each one of them, I would like to do something like:

```
<xs:complexType name="room">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="whatever" type="any type extended from block"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using substitution groups here.

```
<xs:element name="block" abstract="true" type="block"/>

<xs:element name="wall" substitutionGroup="block">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="block">
            <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="height" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="room">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="block" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```